# How does one update XAML Listview PCL?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library

I am new to Xamarin and have some C# knowledge. 
Currently working on a PCL project and I would like to update the a UI page with results from running an async function in the iOS directory.
**XAML Below**

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8" ?>`
<Content Page xmlns = ".....">
   <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout>
         <ListView x:Name="List"/>
      </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Xamarin.CS"**

```
protect void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = DependencyService.Get<IGetItem>();
    var scanActiveIOS = false;
    var scanActiveAndroid = false;

    if (item != null)
    {
        scanActiveIOS = item.VerifyConnectIOS();
        scanActiveAndroid = item.VerifyConnectAndroid();
    }

    if (scanActive IOs)
    {
        ScanLabel.text = "Initiating Scan: iOS";

       **//How do I get list through Interface to update my xaml**
    }
}
```

**Function In Other Code (iOS subdirectories)**

```
public async void doScanning()
{
   scan();
   await Task.Delay(10000); 
   stopScan();
}

private void InterestingThing(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var item = $"{args.item.Name}";
    this.InterestingThing?.Invoke(sender, args.Name);
}
```

**So to BLUF (Bottom Line Up Front)**
I want to get the a copy of the item here to show up on my Interface. Since this is PCL the xaml code is in the directory shared by the .Android and .iOS.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you would define a method in your interface GetInterestingThing() that would return an Item.  Then you could call it via DependencyService.  Or you could use MessagingCenter to send a message from your iOS code to the shared code.

Comment: Thanks @Jason I will research and try your suggestion and post my result/feedback if it does what I intend (or not).